# Polling the keyboard in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, input, keyboard, polling

My Cocoa application should react continuously to the state of the keys pressed by the user. To that end, I would like to poll the keyboard at fixed intervals, instead of relying on keyboard events. Is there any Cocoa API to achieve this? If not, what other options exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polling is never such a great idea. You shouldn't have to do that in most cases.

There is 2 API you may be interested for:

- Quartz Event Taps https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html
- IOKit HID API https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/intro/intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970

Please note keyboard accesses may pose some security issues so the system may not allow you to read the keyboard state. Check the Accessibility settings (access to assistive devices).

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising. You say polling is a bad idea, why is that?

Comment: Most of our machines are now battery powered. Desktop machines are on the decline. Polling has consequences on the battery life, keeping the process and some subsystems (the CPU even) awake when they could have an energy nap.

Answer (score 0):

Don't poll the keyboard, just implement `-keydown:` in your App delegate class.

Comment: That's how I've been doing it so far. How do you propose to keep track of the pressed keys? Store them in a set of some kind?